# Getting loss as "nan" while running CNN (using Keras)

Tags: keras, regression

Need Suggestion

I am trying to design a model to guess Facial-Points. Its a part of Kaggle Competition (https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection).

In this solution, I am trying to design a CNN model (using Keras Library), as a Multi-variable regression model to Predict the co-ordinates of Facial-points.
Issue Faced --> I am getting loss as "nan"

Solutions tried --
1. Tried optimizers - Adam, SGD
2. tested with Learning rate 0.01 to 0.00001
3. Tried with various batch sizes

Can anyone suggest, if I am missing something. The code is present in below link -
https://www.kaggle.com/saurabhrathor/facialpoints-practice

Comment: Try to add batch normalization layers - they have helped me to prevent overflows in network weights in the past

Comment: added the same but got the same result. I am looking for some ways to printout the output of final layer to visually confirm what is it generating. 
But i keras I am not able to find the way.